# iOS - Constantly deleting Derived Data to fix code completion

Tags: xcode, code-completion

In one of my iOS projects I have to constantly delete my Derived Data for the project in order to fix code completion (code sense, whatever you want to call it). Sometimes the delete doesn't even work... code sense will still be broken. Any idea what's wrong with this project?

Comment: If it's any consolation, I'm also having this issue on Xcode 4.3.2. No solution found yet, will post if I find anything but for now I'm just waiting for the next update. This seems to be a widespread issue.

Comment: "Me too".  I was not having this issue with Xcode 4.3.1 to the extent that I now am with 4.3.2.  Apparently there may be a rogue file somewhere in my project file that's causing troubles, there's no way to know what it is.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

1. Change Always Search User Path to NO in Project build settings.
2. Remove -objC flag Other Linker Flags (it is bolded so you can easily find it)

Then clean Derived data and wait a moment for Xcode to reindex.
 This is the only solution which stopped my nightmare (at least at the moment).